# How do i reduce memory usage of this piece of code and improve its speed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, memory

i'm running a for loop that loops over all the rows of a pandas dataframe, then it calculates the euclidean distance from one point at a time to all the other points in the dataframe, then it pass the following point, and do the same thing, and so on.

The thing is that i need to store the value counts of the distances to plot a histogram later, i'm storing this in another pandas dataframe. The problem is that as the second dataframe gets bigger, i will run out of memory at the some time. Not to mention that also as the dataframe size grows, repeating this same loop will get slower, since it will be heavier and harder to handle in memory.

Here's some toy data to reproduce the original problem:

```
import pandas as pd

xx = []
yy = []
tt = []

for i in progressbar(range(1,655556)):
    xx.append(i)
    yy.append(i)
    tt.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['xx'] = xx
df['yy'] = yy
df['tt'] = tt
df['xx'] = df['xx'].apply(lambda x : float(x))
df['yy'] = df['yy'].apply(lambda x : float(x))
df['tt'] = df['tt'].apply(lambda x : float(x))
df
```

This is the original piece of code i was using:

```
counts = pd.DataFrame()

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    dist = pd.Series(np.sqrt((row.xx - df.xx)**2 + (row.yy - df.yy)**2 + (row.tt - df.tt)**2))
    counter = pd.Series(dist.value_counts( sort = True)).reset_index().rename(columns = {'index': 'values', 0:'counts'})   
    counts = counts.append(counter)
```

The original df has a shape of `(695556, 3)` so the expected result should be a dataframe of shape `(695556**3, 2)` containing all the distance values from all the 3 vectors, and their counts. The problem is that this is impossible to fit into my 16gb ram.

So i was trying this instead:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    counts = pd.DataFrame()
    dist = pd.Series(np.sqrt((row.xx - df.xx)**2 + (row.yy - combination.yy)**2 + (row.tt - df.tt)**2))
    counter = pd.Series(dist.value_counts( sort = True)).reset_index().rename(columns = {'index': 'values', 0:'counts'})   
    counts = counts.append(counter)
    counts.to_csv('counts/count_' + str(index) + '.csv')
    del counts
```

In this version, instead of just storing the counts dataframe into memory, i'm writting a csv for each loop. The idea is to put it all together later, once it finishes. This code works faster than the first one, since the time for each loop won't increment as the dataframe grows in size. Although, it still being slow, since it has to write a csv each time. Not to say it will be even slower when i will have to read all of those csv's into a single dataframe.

Can anyone show me how i could optimize this code to achieve these same results but in faster and more memory efficient way?? I'm also open to other implementations, like, spark, dask, or whatever way to achieve the same result: a dataframe containing the value counts for all the distances but that could be more or less handy in terms of time and memory.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You're after 3 billion pair-to-pair distances. Why do you need this?

Comment: Don't ever do this: `counts = counts.append(counter)` in a loop. But if you are looking for pair-wise distances, ditch the data-frame, use some numeric numpy array, and perhaps use sklearn's implementation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html You probably aren't going to be able to beat it.

Comment: I tried this already, but it doesn't really fit what i need. I need to get all the distances from one point to all the rest of points, and then take the distances of the second point to all the other points, and so on. The reason i need this is because i'm working in some 3d printing related project, and i need to have this distances so i can prevent defects from happening during the printing process

Comment: @Miguel2488, you might want to read about the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and [NP-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness).

Comment: My experience of 3D printing is limited to a couple of covert tours of the labs at uni :/ I'd still think that mostly it could be confined to regions and then deal with a printer head reset rather than consider the _entire_ object in all calculations?

Comment: "The reason i need this is because i'm working in some 3d printing related project, and i need to have this distances so i can prevent defects from happening during the printing process"—are you sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627)?

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much for your answer, but tnat approach seems realy complex for my purpose. There is no simpler solution?

Comment: It isn't a solution. It's a description of the problem you're facing, which is more complex than you acknowledge in your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, by solution, i meant "approach". I'm not sure if this is really a TSP since i need to get all the distances, no matter the order, all points need to be walked through

Comment: @Miguel2488, what approach? If the traveling salesman problem and NP-completeness links look like what you want to do you should read further about them. There isn't any known polynomial-time algorithm to solve NP-complete problems, including TSP (and it isn't known if there can _ever be_ one). Basically, as the number of points grows all solutions grow much faster making general solutions prohibitively impractical.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris, i will look deeper into this then

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/